# How do I get Discord Bot to Say Message's Author

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

How do I make it so that, in this case, the bot responds with "Hello," and then the name of the person who used the .hello command?

This is what I have so far.

```
@client.command(pass_context = True)
async def hello(ctx):
    author = ctx.message.author.name
    await ctx.send("Hello", author, "!")
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use f strings. What you can do is

```py
@client.command()
async def hello(ctx):
    await ctx.send(f'hello {ctx.author.name} !')
```

also if you want the user who did the command you can just do `ctx.author`. No need for `ctx.message.author`.